# Visual Studio 2017 does not create a new empty MVC controller in ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm currently developing Web API using ASP.NET Core MVC with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 IDE.

The problem that I'm facing is that whenever I tried to add new empty MVC Controller inside the Controllers folder, it did not appear after the scaffolding process. There is no error whatsoever, its just finishes scaffolding without adding anything to the folder.

Does anyone know why this might happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: close visual studio and re-open it,then check it.

Comment: Did that a few times and still doing the same thing

Comment: some time this happen in visual studio , we don't know why this happen.i faced same issue , at that time i just closed VS and re-opened it,then everything is working fine.

Comment: Especially if you're scaffolding a new *empty* controller, scaffolding is a waste of your time. Just create a new generic class and make it inherit from `Controller`. Same exact end result and no dealing with scaffolding weirdness. Frankly, scaffolding is a mess and always has been. It fails more often than it works, and most of the time it's actually easier to just create things yourself anyways.

Comment: Please check your nuget packages up-to date and clean and build the solution without error.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can try:

Add the Class And Change that Name to `YourClassNameController`,

at the end, make it inherit from `Controller`

Like bellow Code:

```
public class YourClassNameController:Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```